# How to use .tap method to build associated record?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an omniauth authentication model I'm building that's associated to a user.

aka user has many authentications.

I wish to build up key-value pairs of this authentication models using tap because twitter provides a secret key while facebook does not.

So if I have this, I want to accomplish the following conditional statement using the `.tap` method instead.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def apply_omniauth(omni)
    if omni['credentials']['secret']
      self.authentications.build(:provider     => omni['provider'],
                                 :uid          => omni['uid'],
                                 :token        => omni['credentials']['token'],
                                 :token_secret => omni['credentials']['secret']
    else
      self.authentications.build(:provider     => omni['provider'],
                                 :uid          => omni['uid'],
                                 :token        => omni['credentials']['token']
    end
  end

end
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying it this way. Does this accomplish the same as the above?

```
self.authentications.build.tap do |auth|
  auth[:provider]     = omni['provider']               if omni['provider']
  auth[:uid]          = omni['uid']                    if omni['uid']
  auth[:token]        = omni['credentials']['token']   if omni['credentials']['token']
  auth[:token_secret] = omni['credentials']['secret']  if omni['credentials']['secret']
end
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Jesper is it clear now?

Comment: I believe you don't need tap at all, `build` can take a block. Is `'credentials'` key guarantee to be present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simply do (`self` is obsolete here):

```
authentications.build(:provider     => omni['provider'],
                      :uid          => omni['uid'],
                      :token        => omni['credentials']['token'],
                      :token_secret => omni['credentials']['secret'])
```

If any key is missing, this will simply assign nil value. Unless you have some custom logic for setting those attributes, there is no difference between assigning nil or not assigning anything for a new records.